# Anonymous function using polynomial

Tags: octave

Let's say I want to create a rational fraction function in GNU Octave. Can I do it easily using polynomial coefficients?

As example I would like to build

```
f = @(x) x.^2./(2*x^2+3*x+2)
```

using

```
p1 = [1 0 0]
p2 = [2 3 2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use the built-in function `polyval`:

```
p1 = [1 0 0]
p2 = [2 3 2]

f = @(x,p1,p2) polyval(p1,x)./polyval(p2,x)
```

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
p1 = [1 0 0]
p2 = [2 3 2]
```

You can either do

```
f = @(x) sum([x.^2, x, 1].*p1) ./sum([x.^2, x, 1].*p2);
```

or

```
f = @(x,p1,p2) sum([x.^2, x, 1].*p1) ./sum([x.^2, x, 1].*p2);
```

I'd say the second one is clearer if you are going to be trying different polynomial coefficients.

if you want to have flexibility on the order of the polynomials, then you can even go further :

```
f = @(x,p1,p2) sum(x.^[length(p1):-1:0].*p1) ./sum(x.^[length(p2):-1:0].*p2);
```